# Unloading external SWF files

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm loading multiple swf files from the main menu which is never unloaded. I've done this with the following code... Only issue is that instead of unloading to the main menu I just see a white screen as if nothing is loaded.

```
function BackToMenu(i:MouseEvent):void
{
    var BaseMovie:MovieClip = parent.parent as MovieClip;
    BaseMovie.parent.removeChild(BaseMovie);
}
```

EDIT: I'll explain from the start I have a MainMenu.swf. The games are loaded from MainMenu.swf when the button relating to the game is clicked. When a game button is clicked on MainMenu.swf the game loads. When the player completes a game they are presented with the exit button which unloads the current game and shows the MainMenu.swf without having to re-load it.

Comment: Not a clue :s was 13% this morning

Comment: Not sure how it works and to be fair I'm not all that fussed

Comment: Done ... I just didn't notice the click icon on the left until it was explained.

Comment: Alright, then, let's see how we can answer your question...  What do you mean by "unloading to the main menu"?  "unloading" generally means emptying the content from a loader, as in: everything that was loaded is now discarded. This can be done by calling `Loader#unload`or `Loader#unloadAndStop`, but for that to work, all the references to the loaded content must be nullified and/or deleted first. The code you pasted does nothing but remove one specific MovieClip from the display list.  No more, no less.  What exactly is it you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'll explain from the start I have a MainMenu.swf. The games are loaded from MainMenu.swf when the button relating to the game is clicked. When a game button is clicked on MainMenu.swf the game loads. When the player completes a game they are presented with the exit button which unloads the current game and shows the MainMenu.swf without having to re-load it.

Comment: It looks to me like the first issue here is related to all the `parent` calls. My guess is that you are in fact removing the main menu clip, not the loadee. Put a trace on BaseMovie and see what the output is.

Comment: It only traces ... [object MainTimeline]

Comment: There you go. The parent of that is the stage. You are then removing your base movie, so that everything disappears.

Comment: So how would I go about loading a game and keeping the main menu in the background and then when the game is finished only unloading the game so the main menu is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should remove one `parent` to make sure you are actually removing only the game:

```
function BackToMenu(i:MouseEvent):void
{
    var BaseMovie:MovieClip = parent as MovieClip;
    BaseMovie.parent.removeChild(BaseMovie);
}
```

This should take care of your most pressing problem, and allow you to return to the menu.  You have, however, not really unloaded the game, but only removed it from the display list. This often means, that there are still sounds running, active key and/or mouse listeners, etc. - these must all be taken care of!

And, like I said, this will only fix your immediate problem.  It is, however, neither a permanent solution, nor a good one: Since the main SWF is responsible for loading the games, it should also be responsible for disposing of them.  You *should* put cleanup code into your game, but it should only be concerned with stopping any running scripts, sounds, etc. - simple rule: anything that is *started* within the game, should be *stopped* within the game. But it should not try to access objects further up in the display hierarchy, or try to unload itself.

The much better way to do this is by replacing all the above code, and letting the main SWF take care of removing the game, as well as unloading it from memory.  For this, you have to do three things:

1. Instead of writing actual `removeChild` calls, etc., let your button dispatch a custom event to notify the main SWF that it should now be removed:

   ```
   function onBackButtonClicked( event:MouseEvent ):void {
       destroyGame(); // this would be the function that stops all the scripts
       dispatchEvent( new Event( "FINISH_GAME", true ) ); 
   }
   ```

   Note that "FINISH_GAME" is now a "bubbling" event, i.e. it travels downward in the display hierarchy.  We can now listen for this event in any ancestor display object containing the game.
2. In your main SWF, add an event listener to the `Loader` when the game was successfully loaded.  This is done in the event listener that is called when the load process completes:

   ```
   function onLoadComplete( event:Event ):void {
       var loader:Loader = event.target.loader;
       loader.addEventListener( "FINISH_GAME", onFinishGame, true );
   }
   ```
3. Use the corresponding event handler to remove the game clip:

   ```
   function onFinishGame( event:Event ):void {
       var loader:loader = event.currentTarget;
       loader.parent.removeChild( loader );
       loader.unloadAndStop();
   }
   ```

A few more things to consider:

- The naming conventions in ActionScript advise us to use lower case names for methods and variables, and upper case only for types.
- The same naming conventions suggest we use either "on" or "handle" as a prefix for event listeners, along with the name of the event.  Thus, it should be `onBackToMenu` or rather, `onBackButtonClicked`, etc.
- Since I don't know anything about the code you use for loading, I just assumed you have a complete listener, and you don't keep references to the loader.  If you use a member variable, you can use that instead of `event.target`, resp. `event.currentTarget`.